# Can you please suggest the best jvm parameters to my alfresco server

Tags: tomcat, jvm, alfresco

HI,

Alfresco Application is running on tomcat.. The tomcat is not releasing the memory.. The free physical memory is continuously going down..

My JVM parameters are:

set JAVA_OPTS= -Xms4G -Xmx8G -Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=512M   -XX:+UseParallelGC  -server -Dalfresco.home=%ALF_HOME% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

Please provide the suggestions to set the best parameters

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this wiki page: 
[JVM Tuning](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JVM_Tuning)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've given the min size of 4G and max of 8G, how much actual physical memory do you have? You may want to start small, say with min of 1 and max of 2 and observe the behavior via JMX or any other profiling tool.

Comment: Total physical memory:  8,387,692 kbytes
Free physical memory:    518,220 kbytes  -- continuously decreasing from 5GB
Total swap space: 24,267,732 kbytes
Free swap space: 17,631,232 kbytes